# SQL SELECT query excluding an array of id's for infinite scroll

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a fundamentally CRUD application and would like to implement an infinite scroll (React front) where when the user reaches the bottom another 8-10 items are looked up from the database to be shown. I like the scroll more than separate pages.

I would like for the updating `SELECT` from the MySQL to exclude the existing ids that are already being displayed.

So for each updating SQL `SELECT` I would send it an array of ids to ignore/exclude/not include in the returned result when selecting (along with some pre-existing parameters) so that it doesn't produce the same result and can be shown to the user. This array won't be hundreds long but a good couple dozen maybe to be safe.

Does anyone know how I could incorporate the array of values for MySQL to ignore in its `SELECT` process? Is this possible while still being efficent in MySQL/SQL?

Comment: @Shadow in the third paragraph you made a change of "ids not to ignore when selected" when I absolutely want it to ignore the array of ids it is being sent. Ignore, exclude, leave out, not include, etc...

Comment: Why dont you use limit ?

Comment: @KellysOnTop23 I did not make any such change.

Comment: damnnnnnn thats on me